# Deny all URLs unless enabled by annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to deny all requests in Spring boot app unless their method level annotation is fulfilled.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.cors(withDefaults())
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().denyAll()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .addFilterBefore(bamRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
}

@PutMapping(path = "/getInfo")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('GET')")
public ActionResult getInfo(@RequestBody Map<String, String> input) {
    return service.getInfo(input);
}
```

This actually denies the correct user. When I change `.anyRequest().denyAll()` to `.anyRequest().authenticated()` then this controller works, but other controllers are allowed. I want all developers to explicitly configure the security at individual methods.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question better. Do you want to enforce developers to use the `@PreAuthorize` annotation on each controller method and if else, give some kind of error?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Yes, I want Spring to return AccessDeniedException for all requests, unless there is @PreAuthorize annotation at controller method level, that evaluates to true.

Comment: See this -> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deny-access. What you are wanting is there :)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am still deciding if I love or hate their solution :-D

Comment: @LeosLiterak LOL :D

Answer (score 2):

This cannot easily be checked with Spring Security as far as I know, and would likely require some (ugly) reflection (which can be seen in [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deny-access)).

An alternative is to write a unit test for this with [ArchUnit](https://www.archunit.org/). ArchUnit has a clean(er) API, and has the benefit that you can run this during your test-phase rather than having to run or deploy your application first, and then rely on end users noticing some forbidden error.

Such a test would look something like this:

```java
@Test
void ensureEachControllerHasPreAuthorize() {
    JavaClasses importedClasses = new ClassFileImporter().importPackages("com.example.demo");
    ArchRule rule = methods().that()
        .areMetaAnnotatedWith(RequestMapping.class)
        .and().areDeclaredInClassesThat().areMetaAnnotatedWith(Controller.class)
        .should().beAnnotatedWith(PreAuthorize.class)
        .orShould().beDeclaredInClassesThat().areAnnotatedWith(PreAuthorize.class);
    rule.check(importedClasses);
}
```

Some remarks:

- The `areMetaAnnotatedWith(RequestMapping.class)` includes both `@RequestMapping` and variants like `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping`, ... .
- Same applies to the `areMetaAnnotatedWith(Controller.class)` which includes both `@Controller` and `@RestController`.
- I'm allowing both controller methods and classes to be annotated with `@PreAuthorize`. If you only want to pass the test if `@PreAuthorize` is applied on method-level and not at class-level, then you can remove the line that starts with `orShould()`.
- ArchUnit isn't included by default in any of the Spring Boot starters. You'll have to include the dependency by yourself.

Comment: nice approach, thanks